# Write Array with Formats

Tags: arrays, vba, multidimensional-array

Need help from Array VBA expert. Instead of formatting each cell in a range as per code below, is it possible to get this format included in Array so that once it write back to range it is formatted at the same time of writing?

Note that each item in `oArr` has varying formats as shown below

[image]

The current output once I run the code below

[image]

```
Option Explicit

Sub Write_Array_With_Format()

    Dim xArr, aArr, bArr, sArr(), oArr() As Variant, lRow, i As Long, x, A, B As Double

    With Worksheets("Data")    'set data ranges to array
      lRow = .Cells(Rows.Count, 2).End(xlUp).Row
      xArr = .Range(.Cells(6, 2), .Cells(lRow, 2)).Value2
      aArr = .Range(.Cells(6, 3), .Cells(lRow, 3)).Value2
      bArr = .Range(.Cells(6, 4), .Cells(lRow, 4)).Value2
    End With
    
    ReDim sArr(LBound(xArr, 1) To UBound(xArr, 1), 1 To 1) 'String Array
    
    sArr = Array("x A B", "A x B", "A B x", "x B A", "B x A", "B A x")
    
    sArr = Application.Transpose(sArr)
    
    ReDim oArr(LBound(xArr, 1) To UBound(xArr, 1), 1 To 1) 'Output Array
    
    For i = 1 To UBound(xArr, 1)
    
        x = xArr(i, 1): A = aArr(i, 1): B = bArr(i, 1)
        
        If x > A And x > B And A > B Then
            oArr(i, 1) = sArr(1, 1)
        
        ElseIf x < A And x > B And A > B Then
            oArr(i, 1) = sArr(2, 1)

        ElseIf x < A And x < B And A > B Then
            oArr(i, 1) = sArr(3, 1)

        ElseIf x > A And x > B And A < B Then
            oArr(i, 1) = sArr(4, 1)

        ElseIf x > A And x < B And A < B Then
            oArr(i, 1) = sArr(5, 1)

        ElseIf x < A And x < B And A < B Then
            oArr(i, 1) = sArr(6, 1)
                
        End If

    Next
    
    With Worksheets("Data")
        .Range(.Cells(6, 5), .Cells(lRow, 5)).Value2 = oArr 'write Output Array to Range
        
        For i = 6 To lRow   'Format values
            
            If .Range("E" & i).Value = "x A B" Then
                With .Range("E" & i)
                    With .Characters(1, 1).Font
                        .Color = vbBlue
                    End With
                    With .Characters(3, 3).Font
                        .Underline = True
                        .Color = vbGreen
                    End With
                End With
            
            ElseIf .Range("E" & i).Value = "A x B" Then
                With .Range("E" & i)
                    With .Characters(1, 2).Font
                        .Color = vbGreen
                        .Underline = True
                    End With
                    With .Characters(3, 1).Font
                        .Underline = True
                        .Color = vbBlue
                    End With
                    With .Characters(5, 1).Font
                        .Color = vbGreen
                    End With
                End With
            
            'And so on and so forth.............
            
            End If
        Next
    
    End With
    
End Sub
```

Comment: You only have 6 distinct formats, so you could copy-paste from the first table or any pre-formatted range, instead of using the `Characters` collection for each cell.  You can't store that type of formatting in your array

Comment: @TimWilliams thanks for the response, the formats are actually more than 6, it is 76 type of formats. Just made it 6 to explain it in simple way..

Comment: Please, try explaining how can  be 76 formats type, using only three characters (space separated) in the string? Could there be other characters, except A B and x?

Comment: @FaneDuru sorry for confusion, the 76 formats are actually based on 5 characters plus  4 spaces in between `"A B C D x"` or `"x A B C D"` or `"A x B C D"` or etc... with varying colors and varying underlined letter combinations. I just made it 3 to simply explain whether it is possible to get this format to array and write the format together with values to range.

Comment: I am afraid that you did not proceed as it should... The solution for your problem resides in a separate sub/function able to process **each string type/letter combination**, not each cell. I started preparing a piece of code to exemplify what it should be done, but based on combinations of the shown characters... I do not have too much time right now, but after solving an urgent situation I will post it.

Comment: @FaneDuru Thanks, the format values loop I made above are looking for each cells then format each cells one by one. I just newly discovered Array, and notice if the format can be done in Array, this will really help to run faster. This code to be used for 2000+ xlsb files containing thousands of data each file.

Comment: Iteration itself can be done on the array range, but **an array cannot keep format**. It can keep objects (ranges), but each such object (cell) must be formatted. If you would have less format types, the code can be improved, from this point of view, if each category is placed in a `Union` range and the format to be done at once, at the code end. But your example, having 6 different types is not suitable for such an approach. How many occurrences of the same type do you estimate to exist in a real range to be processed?

Comment: It's always better to let us know if you've "simplified" your actual use case - approaches which might work for what you posted might fall apart or not be the best approach when scaled up...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Please, try using the next approach. The code will iterate between the array elements, but it is not possible to keep format in an array... It will process each array element, only incrementing its rows, according to each case definition (in a separate Sub):

```
Sub testCellFormat()
 'Dim dict As New Scripting.Dictionary, i As Long
 Dim sh As Worksheet, lastR As Long, arr, oArr, sArr, arrFin, i As Long
 
 Set sh = ActiveSheet
 lastR = sh.Range("B" & sh.rows.count).End(xlUp).row
 sh.Range("E6:E" & lastR).Font.Color = vbBlack 'just to reset the range for the second test...
 sh.Range("E6:E" & lastR).Font.Underline = False
 
 arr = sh.Range("B6:D" & lastR).Value2            'place all the range in a single aray
 sArr = Array("x A B", "A x B", "A B x", "x B A", "B x A", "B A x") 'A 1 D array is good enough, too
 
 ReDim oArr(1 To UBound(arr), 1 To 1)
 For i = 1 To UBound(arr)
        If arr(i, 1) > arr(i, 2) And arr(i, 1) > arr(i, 3) And arr(i, 2) > arr(i, 3) Then
            oArr(i, 1) = sArr(0)
        ElseIf arr(i, 1) < arr(i, 2) And arr(i, 1) > arr(i, 3) And arr(i, 2) > arr(i, 3) Then
            oArr(i, 1) = sArr(1)
        ElseIf arr(i, 1) < arr(i, 2) And arr(i, 1) < arr(i, 3) And arr(i, 2) > arr(i, 3) Then
            oArr(i, 1) = sArr(2)
        ElseIf arr(i, 1) > arr(i, 2) And arr(i, 1) > arr(i, 3) And arr(i, 2) < arr(i, 3) Then
            oArr(i, 1) = sArr(3)
        ElseIf arr(i, 1) > arr(i, 2) And arr(i, 1) < arr(i, 3) And arr(i, 2) < arr(i, 3) Then
            oArr(i, 1) = sArr(4)
        ElseIf arr(i, 1) < arr(i, 2) And arr(i, 1) < arr(i, 3) And arr(i, 2) < arr(i, 3) Then
            oArr(i, 1) = sArr(5)
        End If
    Next
    sh.Range("E" & 6).Resize(UBound(oArr), 1).value = oArr 'drop the array content
    For i = 1 To UBound(oArr)
        cellFormat sh.Range("E" & i + 5) 'process the necessary range (built using the iteration variable)
    Next i
End Sub

Sub cellFormat(rngE As Range)
   Dim T As String: T = rngE.value
   Dim boolUnderscore, boolGreen, boolRed, boolBlue
   If Len(T) <> 5 Then Exit Sub
   Select Case left(T, 3)
        Case "x A"
            rngE.Characters(1, 1).Font.Color = vbBlue
            With rngE.Characters(3, 3).Font
                .Color = vbGreen
                .Underline = True
            End With
        Case "A x"
            rngE.Characters(1, 3).Font.Underline = True
            rngE.Characters(1, 2).Font.Color = vbGreen
            rngE.Characters(3, 3).Font.Color = vbBlue
            rngE.Characters(5, 1).Font.Color = vbGreen
        Case "A B"
            rngE.Characters(1, 4).Font.Color = vbGreen
            rngE.Characters(5, 1).Font.Color = vbBlue
            rngE.Characters(3, 3).Font.Underline = True
        Case "x B"
            rngE.Characters(1, 3).Font.Underline = True
            rngE.Characters(1, 1).Font.Color = vbBlue
            rngE.Characters(2, 5).Font.Color = vbRed
        Case "B x"
            rngE.Characters(3, 5).Font.Underline = True
            rngE.Font.Color = vbRed
            rngE.Characters(3, 1).Font.Color = vbBlue
        Case "B A"
            With rngE.Characters(1, 3).Font
                .Color = vbRed
                .Underline = True
            End With
            rngE.Characters(5, 1).Font.Color = vbBlue
   End Select
End Sub
```

I asked about the occurrences number of the same string type. If there are many, the code can be optimized (I can do that) to use a dictionary where to keep a `Union` range to be formatted at once, of the end. **But pere every category type**. If not too many cases for the same string type, not much to be gain...

According to the used algorithm, the string types used by the second sub, can be kept in an array and use them a little more efficient.

**Edited**:

Please, try the following optimized solution. It will firstly place the unique strings from `oArr` (col E:E) in a dictionary (as keys) and as items `Union` ranges of (built) similar cells (in E:E). Then, it will process/format the `Union` ranges, at once:

```
Sub testCellFormat()
 Dim sh As Worksheet, lastR As Long, arr, oArr, sArr, arrFin, i As Long
 Dim dict As Object ' New Scripting.Dictionary
 
 Set sh = ActiveSheet
 lastR = sh.Range("B" & sh.rows.count).End(xlUp).row
 sh.Range("E6:E" & lastR).Font.Color = vbBlack 'just to reset the range for the second test...
 sh.Range("E6:E" & lastR).Font.Underline = False
 
 arr = sh.Range("B6:D" & lastR).Value2            'place all the range in a single aray
 sArr = Array("x A B", "A x B", "A B x", "x B A", "B x A", "B A x") 'a 1 D array is good enough, too
 
 ReDim oArr(1 To UBound(arr), 1 To 1)
 For i = 1 To UBound(arr)                             'iterate between the array rows and appropriately fill oArr elements:
        If arr(i, 1) > arr(i, 2) And arr(i, 1) > arr(i, 3) And arr(i, 2) > arr(i, 3) Then
            oArr(i, 1) = sArr(0)
        ElseIf arr(i, 1) < arr(i, 2) And arr(i, 1) > arr(i, 3) And arr(i, 2) > arr(i, 3) Then
            oArr(i, 1) = sArr(1)
        ElseIf arr(i, 1) < arr(i, 2) And arr(i, 1) < arr(i, 3) And arr(i, 2) > arr(i, 3) Then
            oArr(i, 1) = sArr(2)
        ElseIf arr(i, 1) > arr(i, 2) And arr(i, 1) > arr(i, 3) And arr(i, 2) < arr(i, 3) Then
            oArr(i, 1) = sArr(3)
        ElseIf arr(i, 1) > arr(i, 2) And arr(i, 1) < arr(i, 3) And arr(i, 2) < arr(i, 3) Then
            oArr(i, 1) = sArr(4)
        ElseIf arr(i, 1) < arr(i, 2) And arr(i, 1) < arr(i, 3) And arr(i, 2) < arr(i, 3) Then
            oArr(i, 1) = sArr(5)
        End If
    Next
    
    sh.Range("E" & 6).Resize(UBound(oArr), 1).Value2 = oArr 'drop the array content
    
    'place the not formatted range in a dictionary. Keys as oArr elements and items as (Union) build range:
    Set dict = CreateObject("Scripting.Dictionary")
    For i = 1 To UBound(arr)
        If Not dict.Exists(oArr(i, 1)) Then
            dict.Add oArr(i, 1), sh.Range("E" & i + 5)
        Else
            Set dict(oArr(i, 1)) = Union(dict(oArr(i, 1)), sh.Range("E" & i + 5))
        End If
    Next
    'some optimization
    With Application
        .ScreenUpdating = False:
        .Calculation = xlCalculationManual
        .EnableEvents = False
    End With
    
    For i = 1 To UBound(oArr) 'iterate between oArr rows
        cellFormatDict CStr(oArr(i, 1)), sArr, dict 'format each dictionary Union ranges, at once
    Next i
    
    With Application
        .ScreenUpdating = True
        .Calculation = xlCalculationAutomatic
        .EnableEvents = True
    End With
    MsgBox "Ready...", vbInformation, "Job done."
End Sub

Sub cellFormatDict(strCond As String, sArr, dict As Object)
    Select Case left(dict(strCond), 3)
        Case left(sArr(0), 3)   ' "x A"
            With dict(strCond)
                .Characters(1, 1).Font.Color = vbBlue
                With .Characters(3, 3).Font
                    .Color = vbGreen
                    .Underline = True
                End With
            End With
        Case left(sArr(1), 3)   ' "A x"
           With dict(strCond)
                .Characters(1, 3).Font.Underline = True
                .Characters(1, 2).Font.Color = vbGreen
                .Characters(3, 3).Font.Color = vbBlue
                .Characters(5, 1).Font.Color = vbGreen
            End With
         Case left(sArr(2), 3)   ' "A B"
            With dict(strCond)
                .Characters(1, 4).Font.Color = vbGreen
                .Characters(5, 1).Font.Color = vbBlue
                .Characters(3, 3).Font.Underline = True
            End With
         Case left(sArr(3), 3)  ' "x B"
            With dict(strCond)
                .Characters(1, 3).Font.Underline = True
                .Characters(1, 1).Font.Color = vbBlue
                .Characters(2, 5).Font.Color = vbRed
            End With
         Case left(sArr(4), 3)  ' "B x"
            With dict(strCond)
                .Characters(3, 5).Font.Underline = True
                .Font.Color = vbRed
                .Characters(3, 1).Font.Color = vbBlue
            End With
         Case left(sArr(5), 3)  ' "B A"
            With dict(strCond)
                With .Characters(1, 3).Font
                    .Color = vbRed
                    .Underline = True
                End With
                .Characters(5, 1).Font.Color = vbBlue
            End With
    End Select
End Sub
```

Its efficiency will be more visible in big ranges having more occurrences of the same strings (in E:E).

Please, test both versions and send feedback about the efficiency difference.

In order to rapidly create a testing environment, I created the next sub to multiply the existing (shown) testing range. Multiplying it by 500 times, I obtained a range of 3004 rows, which could be processed in about 30 seconds. Changing the format is something consuming time... Using the `Union` ranges looks to be the single way to make a relatively fast code for such a purpose, I think.

Comment: thanks for the response.. there are actually thousands of occurrence per file.. will try this out..

Comment: @Tope Not occurrences in general... **Occurrences of the same string/category**... If you confirm that this is the case and the meaning of your comment, when I will be at home (after some hours) I will try thinking about a solution, too

Comment: I will show you a way.  Now I am driving...

Comment: Once you've formatted one cell for any given format, you can copy/paste it for any later occurrences of the same pattern.

Comment: @Tim Williams Yes, it is possible, but using clipboard to copy a cell it will take similar time to format the cell in discussion, if not more. What I wanted to suggest was using a dictionary loaded with `Union` ranges of similar (processed) strings taken from `oArr` array. Then formatting the `Union` ranges (dictionary items) at the end of the code. It should be much faster. I will prepare such a code version...

Comment: @FaneDuru - you're right about relative speed.  I had the idea that using `Characters` to set formatting is relatively slow, but apparently not as nearly as slow as copying a single cell repeatedly.  Nor would I ever have guessed you could use `Characters` on a multi-cell range.

Comment: @FaneDuru Many thanks, this is way faster!!

Comment: @FaneDuru as requested for the feedback, I made a test for 5 files containing average of 7000 rows of data. The test run was made 5 times comparing the average speed of **1st code** `Write_Array_With_Format`  and **your code** `testCellFormat`. The outcome is the **1st code** is about 3.2 times faster than **your code**

Comment: @Tope I'm afraid I cannot get you... Do you want saying that **your code is faster for 5 files with about 7000 rows**? Did you test the version after **Edited**? If so, can you share one of the workbook you made tests on?